# Setting a relative file reference for XmlReader

Tags: c#, asp.net

Today for testing I'm using:

```
XmlReader ProductDoc = XmlReader.Create(@"c:\inetpub\wwwroot\data\xml\foo\bar.xml", settings);
```

I need to make this more relative instead of a fully qualified name but can't seem to find a way to make it work.

I really don't have a lot of access to the web.config file and so don't want to go there.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is What you need

```
Server.MapPath("/data/xml/foo/bar.xml")
```

Documentation is [present here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I knew it'd be simple. I used 'string path = Server.MapPath(@"\data\xml\foo\bar.xml");XmlReader ProductDoc = XmlReader.Create(path, settings);'